# Errors are not identified in quickfix window

Tags: errorformat

I am using TI compiler and when I build and errors appear in quick fix, they are not identified.  The errors look like this **in terminal**:

```
"/home/sporty/HydroGuardFW/hw_2_0/hg_os/coap_resources/system_session.h", line 79: error #136: class "Sessions" has no member "session_success"
```

Here is how it looks in **VIM**, its the second line:

```
|| "/home/sporty/ti/ccsv8/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_18.1.3.LTS/bin/cl430" -vmspx --data_model=large --near_data=none -O2 --opt_for_speed=1 --use_hw_mpy=F5 --include_path="/home/sporty/ti/ccsv8/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="/home/sporty/HydroGuardFW/hw_2_0/hg_os" --include_path="/home/sporty/HydroGuardFW/hw_2_0" --include_path="/home/sporty/HydroGuardFW/hw_2_0" --include_path="/home/sporty/ti/ccsv8/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_18.1.3.LTS/include" --define=__MSP430F5359__ --define=HYDRO_GUARD --define=NDEBUG -g --symdebug:dwarf_version=4 --c++14 --printf_support=minimal --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="hg_os/cli/commands.d_raw" --obj_directory="hg_os/cli"  "../hg_os/cli/commands.cpp"
|| "/home/sporty/HydroGuardFW/hw_2_0/hg_os/coap_resources/system_session.h", line 79: error #136: class "Sessions" has no member "session_success"
|| "../hg_os/cli/commands.cpp", line 195: error #136: class "Modem" has no member "session_success"
|| "../hg_os/cli/commands.cpp", line 201: error #141: too many arguments in function call
```

I tried using the following *errorformat* configruation

```
set errorformat=\"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l:\ %m
```

Comment: The line from "terminal" and the 2nd line from "vim" you pointed out are identical. Did you make a cut&paste error?

Comment: I copied your terminal line to a file `errors` and opened that file as a quickfix list with `vim -q errors`. The line in the resulting quickfix list looked as it should: `/home/sporty/HydroGuardFW/hw_2_0/hg_os/coap_resources/system_session.h|79| error #136: class "Sessions" has no member "session_success"`. So you shouldn't have to change Vim's default `'errorformat'` for it to work.

Comment: @nst0022, the line in terminal is the raw compiler output, the second line demonstrates how that line is shown in VIM.  VIM simply adds **||** to the beginning of the line instead of matching it as an error.

Comment: @garyjohn, Opening errors file with the -q option pointed me in the right direction.  Solved!! The issue was in asyncrun.vim configuration.

Comment: @user1135541: Got it. Then I guess you simply missed the `error %n` part in your format string.